# PHP date minus X days

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code in PHP:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-7 days"))
```

which i am using in an SQL Query:

```
$sql="SELECT * from billing_invoices WHERE due_date <= '".date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-7 days"))."' AND (status = 'Unpaid' or status = 'Part Paid') AND statement = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' group by customer_sequence ";
```

so if the date is `2014-12-16` it will show `2014-12-09`

i want to be able to run this Query too:

```
$sql="SELECT * from billing_invoices WHERE due_date <= '".date($_POST["date"], strtotime("-7 days"))."' AND (status = 'Unpaid' or status = 'Part Paid') AND statement = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' group by customer_sequence ";
```

but the date being returned is the current day rather than -7 days from the `POSTED` date

Comment: What is $_POST["date"] format? is it "Y-m-d"? or a time_stamp?

Comment: why did you do this wiht php? **SELECT DATE_SUB('1998-01-02', INTERVAL 7 DAY);** see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: `date(strtotime(date($_POST["date"] . ' -7 days'));`?

Comment: @putvande will it work? I think you still need to add `date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date($_POST["date"] . ' -7 days'));` or in OP's case `date($_POST["date"], strtotime(date($_POST["date"] . ' -7 days'));`

Comment: use as :-<?php
$strtotime = strtotime($_POST['date']);
date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-7 days',$strtotime));
?>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the PHP Manual for [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) there is a second parameter where you can specify a timestamp wich is then used instead of the current time

```
int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now ] )
```

So your code should look like this:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-7 days", $_POST["date"]))
```

Perhaps you have to convert your date to a timestamp before. Dependent on your date format in `$_POST["date"]` this may work:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-7 days", strtotime($_POST["date"])))
```

Answer (score 0):

use

> INTERVEL

```
$sql="SELECT * from billing_invoices WHERE DATE_SUB(due_date , INTERVAL -7 DAY)' AND (status = 'Unpaid' or status = 'Part Paid') AND statement = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' group by customer_sequence ";
```

OR

```
$sql="SELECT * from billing_invoices WHERE DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)' AND (status = 'Unpaid' or status = 'Part Paid') AND statement = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' group by customer_sequence ";
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't know what's `date($_POST["date"], strtotime("-7 days"))`.... So you can use this...

```
$sql="SELECT * from billing_invoices WHERE due_date <= '".DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)."' AND (status = 'Unpaid' or status = 'Part Paid') AND statement = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' group by customer_sequence ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DATE_SUB / INTERVAL function within MySQL to perform this check.

*NB. - Make sure you escape the value being input into your SQL.

```
 $sql="SELECT * 
   FROM billing_invoices 
   WHERE due_date <= DATE(DATE_SUB(".$_POST['date'].", INTERVAL -7 DAY))
   AND (status = 'Unpaid' OR status = 'Part Paid') 
   AND statement = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
   GROUP BY customer_sequence;";
```

You can find more information on using DATE_SUB / INTERVAL here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub